# Mysql Group By and Sum Total of the column values

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd3B3.png) I am having one table like id, sale_id, item_total, tax fields. need to sum the item_total by grouping the tax values.

### Table 1

### id    |   sale_id  |     item_cost_price   |      tax |

### 1     |      10    |          150          |       5  |

### 2     |      10    |           50          |       7  |

### 3     |       10   |           30          |       5  |

this is required output:

---

### id    |   sale_id  |     item_cost_price   |      tax |

### 1     |      10    |          180          |       5  |

### 2     |      10    |           50          |       7  |

When i tried this query,

```
   SELECT sale_id,tax  FROM bgs_ib_sales_items GROUP BY tax

                $query=$this->db->query("SELECT sale_id,tax  FROM bgs_ib_sales_items GROUP BY tax ");

            echo $num = $query->num_rows();
            $result=array();

                foreach($query->result() as $row){
                     $result_row[]=$row->sale_id;
                     $result_row[]=$row->tax;
                     $result_row[]=$row->item_cost_price;

                }
```

My output is:
i am getting output like this,

am getting distinct tax only. but i need to sum item total values.

Note:

Image 1 : refer my datatable
 Image 2:  refer my expected output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE0Sq.png)

Comment: Your query is nonsensical. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: May be  `SELECT SUM(item_total),tax  FROM bgs_ib_sales_items GROUP BY tax`

Comment: Need Group by tax, SUM(item_cost_price )with where condition like my query..       SELECT SUM(item_total),tax FROM bgs_ib_sales_items GROUP BY tax Where s_id = 10

Comment: but not getting required output

Comment: Can you show the result of print_r($query); after $query?

Comment: sir. here i have mentioning table with column fields in table 1 (see the above table). table 2 describes required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `SUM(item_cost_price)` in SELECT statement.

In your select statement your select only sale_id, tax. But what you echo are sale_id, tax, and **item_cost_price** which not exist in your SELECT statement. Try This:-

```
    $sql = "SELECT sale_id,tax, SUM(item_cost_price ) AS TotalPrice FROM bgs_ib_sales_items WHERE sale_id = '10' GROUP BY tax";

    $query=$this->db->query($sql);

    foreach($query->result() as $row){
      $result_row[]=$row->sale_id;
      $result_row[]=$row->tax;
      $result_row[]=$row->TotalPrice;

    }
```

Comment: @SardharMohamedM then please tick is as an answer.